# Is \textcelsius in Xcharter supposed to complain about U+0089?

Tags: degrees, xcharter

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{XCharter}  %% we want to go lualatex, so no more charter...

\begin{document}

\meaning\textcelsius

Show 2\textcelsius\  = 2 degrees Celsius.

\end{document}
```

gives as the error

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+0089) in font XCharter1-Roman-ts1!
```

Alas, shouldn't the celsius degree symbol be U+00B0?

It's also not that rare a symbol, so I am surprised that XCharter does not contain one and/or that the XCharter package wouldn't have a working redefinition (at the very least, something like `$^o$`, ugly though it may be), or even throw an error for such a case that prompts the writer to do something about it.  Just a warning with a U+0089 (within the other hundreds of tex log messages) and a blank in the document seems less than ideal, does it not?

There are many easy patch solutions.  What's the recommended one?

Comment: If you use LuaLaTeX you shouldn't do `\usepackage{XCharter}`; load the font via `\fontspec` instead. Alas, the glyph is missing also in the OpenType font.

Comment: if you do `\DeclareEncodingSubset{TS1}{XCharter-TLF}{10}` after xcharter, a substituation will be used. But as egreg says the package is not for lualatex.

Comment: The correct Unicode equivalent for `\textcelsius` would actually be U+2103: ℃. This glyph should be included in the `XCharter` package according to its doc.

Comment: and if you want an error use `\tracinglostchars=3`.